# Baking onto different uvmaps

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv

Let's say I have a object that has a uvmap called uv1 and has a color,roughness,bump etc applied in cycles through image textures with texture coordinate set to uv using uv1 and the image textures are meant for uv1, is it possible to transfer the colour,bump etc to another image which uses another uvmap uv2.
Note: it would be easy for me to do so if the object was textured using procedurals all I have to do is bake the textures using uv2, but I hand painted details onto the object using uv1

Answer (score 1):

Cycles bakes with the active (selected) UV map and to the selected Image node.

[image]